# Label points with function aggregate in a scatter plot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

How can I add, in the chart below, labels for points grouping by: category (KEY) that exceeds (>) the mean of the category + 2?

I just managed to add labels to points (regardless of category) that exceed a certain value (20). Below.

```
geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(PRODVENDA>20,as.character(Projeto),'')), 
            hjust=0,vjust=0, show.legend = FALSE
```

I try combine the functions aggregate, but i couldn't. It is possible?

[image]

```
prodVenda_KEY <- ggplot(dfProjeto, aes(Projeto, PRODVENDA, group=KEY,color=KEY, shape=KEY)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(dfProjeto$KEY)), size = 2.5) + 
  labs(title = "Sales productivity") + xlab('')+ ylab('') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(PRODVENDA>20,as.character(Projeto),'')), 
            hjust=0,vjust=0, show.legend = FALSE)
```

Reproducible example of my data:

```
Projeto    Key            PRODVENDA
(code)     (text)         (number productivity)
```

```
2020      Web-service     20
2074      Web-service     15
8787      XLS             12
```

Thanks!

Comment: please provide a reproducible example of your data to help us help you.

Comment: You can try to subset the data:  `geom_text(data=dfProjeto[dfProjeto$PRODVENDA>20,], aes(label=as.character(Projeto)), 
          hjust=0,vjust=0, show.legend = FALSE)`

Comment: Consider, basically that I have the structure below (I've simplified, but I think that's enough).


    
-**"Projeto"** (Contains the name of the project -> Text)
- **"Key"** (Main characteristics of projects -> Text)
- **"PRODVENDA"** (Contains the sale productivity of the project -> Number)

Comment: I edited the question to add an reproducible example of my data.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the functions aggregate. Can you explain exactly what you want your chart to look like? Regardless of what type of aggregate you're trying to do, this sample of data is probably too small for it to be useful for us reproducing what you want